# How do I get OK Google to work on Google Chrome and be Always On?

Tags: google-chrome

Version 37.0.2062.76 beta (64-bit) installed, can't get Ok Google to turn on. I've done google searches on how to get this to work but nothing seems to be working for me. Does anyone have this working or do you remember how you got this working?

Comment: I'm having the same problem on 37.0.2062.120 (64-bit). "OK Google" is enabled in settings.